# Obtain FileVault 2 recovery key with administrator account

Tags: macos, filevault, encryption

I enabled full disk encryption on my new MacBook Pro.  (I am new to the Mac world but an accomplished Linux/UNIX and Windows type)

However, I made a mistake and skipped the step of taking note of the recovery key.

Is is possible to get the recovery key at this point?

Comment: I'd appreciate the answer and not the downvote even if it is a reference to somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe you should make the title of your question more precise so that people see what CoreStorage issue you are addressing.

Comment: I agree with you on the nonsense down vote without comment at least. However your question should be reworded since it is not possible you missed the screen with that information, and the way you are asking could be read as "how to crack the encryption key" But here is some info for you to read https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837

Comment: OK, so I apparently missed it for some reason.  Can I get a new recovery information by unencryption and the re-encryption?

Comment: Re-encryption is the standard cure for most Filevault2 / CoreStorage issues :)

Comment: I redid the encryption, you get to the key recovery option to select between either putting the information into the iCloud drive or to create a recovery key.  I selected NEITHER and it allowed me to continue and did NOT display the recovery key information and nothing was put on my iCloud drive.  This is OSX 10.10.6

Comment: I selected using my iCloud drive for the recovery key.....however I just looked into my iCloud drive and do not see any file should I be concerned?

Answer (score 21):

It seems strange OS X didn't present you the recovery key. Try:

```
sudo fdesetup changerecovery -personal
```

This awesome [blog](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/managing-mavericks-filevault-2-with-fdesetup/) has probably all the info you desire. Look for the section "*Managing individual and institutional recovery keys*". You can use your Filevault2 password to change the recovery key. And you will have to use an Administrator account.

Comment: Interesting....what is the purpose of the encryption if it is so easy to bypass?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD You still need to provide your unlock key (recovery or account).

Comment: If you are an administrator you should be able to obtain this information.  I'd think that this would be something legit.

Comment: I think this is where OS X differs from other *nix. Many people use Admin as their everyday account. Apple needs to protect those ;)

Comment: @Buscar웃SD, it's possible to get a recovery key because your account is enabled for FileVault 2 and is associated with a key that can unlock the encryption. An account which is not enabled for FileVault would not be able to generate a new recovery key because its password would not be associated with a key which can unlock the encryption.

Comment: @RichTrouton Thank you, I think i got it....When you turn on FileVault, it creates a recovery key which you can used to reset your login password. This provides protection against losing your data in case you forget your login password.

When FileVault disk encryption is on, you need to use the recovery key instead of your Apple ID, to reset your login password.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the correct answer to this question is that you cannot find a FileVault Recovery Key for an already encrypted disk. You can only learn it when you enable FileVault. If you want to know it you need to decrypt and start over.

If you don't know the recovery key, you don't know the FileVault 2 encryption password, and you cannot boot into a user account with unlock privileges you cannot recover the drive.

Apple wants you to store the recovery key in iCloud. That is something I will personally do in the future. Be sure your iCloud password is recoverable in the case of drive failure (I like to keep a printed copy in addition to my 1Password).

If you want to manage recovery keys for a set of drives and computers you can study these recommendations:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202385

Comment: Reading this page I still think it's not possible to find out what the recovery key is post-encryption, but it sounds like it's possible to change the recovery key (see other replies).